# Question about RF waves and it's effect on electronic devices

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, watts

Could a let's say 50 W RF wave (2.40 GHz and 5 GHz) cause disturbance in nearby devices like Laptops? (Data corruption, random opening of applications and programs, random commands, etc.)

Comment: The only answer possible is "yes" i.e. 50 watts **could** cause a disturbance that is of the "etc." variety. In other words, you probably need to think about your question and target something more meaningful and direct; something that can be answered rather than discussed.

Comment: 50W of microwave at close distance would cause disturbance to the human! 

Put your laptop in a microwave oven and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

*This was supposed to be a comment but took too long.*

50W power (if the transmission power or effective radiated power is meant) equals 47 dBm. As a comparison, home- or office-use Wi-Fi modems' transmission power is about 20 dBm at 2.4 GHz. And a +3 dBm difference means double power. So, 50W/47dBm is a good amount of power.

Without knowing the antenna characteristics (i.e. radiation pattern), the exact frequency of the transmitted wave (when you say RF it can be anything e.g. 100s of GHz), the distance between the source and the receiver, the "possible" or "approximated" sensitivity of the victim (laptop, in your case) it's difficult to answer.

Also, I'm not saying/thinking this and I have no intention of making a suspicion, but others may raise a concern as it's unclear if this is going to be used for illegal purposes such as harming people by damaging their laptops.

Comment: I edited the question and put 2.40 GHz and 5 GHz, basically where most devices operate